# Linux kernel 4.4 Android devices

Tags: linux, kernel

I am trying to find out what all devices are running linux kernel 4.4+ and having a hard time finding all. Till now I could only find Sony Xperia devices running kernel 4.4.

The reason I was trying to get a 4.4 linux device is I am having a hard time compiling kernels based on 3.1x on my ubuntu linux 4.15 so I thought it would be nice to have a linux 4.4 device in that respect. I was trying to compile perf tool for linux right now.

Comment: Not even Oreo is on Linux kernel 4, so I doubt anything is

Comment: A bunch of SDM835/845 devices already got 4.x, either on stock on on custom ROM. Sammy S9 got 4.4, Xiaomi Mi 6 / Mix 2 got 4.4, Mix 2S even got 4.9. Still, I believe finding a comprehensive list of it is considered off-topic (and I voted as such).